# Authentication for twitter API and Rest Call

Tags: rest, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have been using FB api for some simple demo and everything was quite easy with the authentication. Now I have to do something similar with twitter v1.1 but there is something that I really don't understand...

Example:
I want to do this request:
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=q=%23freebandnames

the problem is that I have to be authenticated, anyone have some examples? I don't want to create a twitter connection because I don't need different users to be connected to my applicaiton. I have just to perform some simple search request but I can't understand how to use the authentication parameters. Which type of Ajax request I have to use in order to perform the REST request authenticated??? (Obviously I have my secret token and my access secret token) but how to use them????

THanks in advance for answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use this javascript library: [codebird-js](https://github.com/mynetx/codebird-js) with the "Application-only auth".**

or

**Do it yourself: everything is explained in [the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth).**

Basically you need to follow 3 steps (and you should do the 2 first just once):

> - An application encodes its consumer key and secret into a specially encoded set of credentials.
> - An application makes a request to the POST oauth2/token endpoint to exchange these credentials for a bearer token.
> - When accessing the REST API, the application uses the bearer token to authenticate.

The steps are detailed in the documentation.

You can do the first 2 separately and when you get your bearer token, you need to add a specific HTTP Header (Authorization) in each request with your bearer token (that's the 3rd step). With jQuery it could be something like that:

```
$.ajax({
  headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer '+$my_bearer_token },
  url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q='+$search
}).done(function (data) {
  // Play with the data
});
```