# communicating with twitter api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, twitter

I need help getting info on twitter users with angularJS, by search
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/search

I've got the authintication params

> Access Token  someToken
>
> Access Token Secret   someTokenSecret
>
> Access Level  Read and write
>
> Owner : me
>
> Owner ID  :some ID

I don't know where should I put the authintication params

how can do this with some ajax request? like this:

```
  $http({
     method: "GET",
     dataType: 'json',
     url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23freebandnames&since_id=24012619984051000&max_id=250126199840518145&result_type=mixed&count=4"
 }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
     $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
     console.log(myWelcome);
 }, function myError(response) {
     $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
 });
  });
```

I'd love some example or explanation, cause I'm lost with this one..

Comment: It is first necessary to perform a set of API calls to authentify yourself. This is rather done server-side. You may want ot use a library performing this. cf. https://dev.twitter.com/oauth

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication for twitter API and Rest Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136092/authentication-for-twitter-api-and-rest-call)